# A Ressource-Monitor that saves Ressources usage of 1 program over a long time and displays it

Tags: windows

What I need:
A Graph Display like you'd see in the Task Manager, not just Data as Text.
A Software or full script, not a half-baked solution (a way to do it with perfmon would be fine).
Only Info on RAM usage and maybe CPU usage, if that helps.
A graph that goes over hours, I wanna see if the usage spikes or if the program has a memory leak.

Comment: Any such thing would be intrusive. That is, it will affect the program itself.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? The Task Manager provides this info in real time by itself, but just not over a longer time

Comment: The Task Manager is not very accurate.  Have you tried procmon from sysinternals?  If you just need memory usage, you can easily do that in your own application.

Comment: I couldn't find any info on using procmon for RAM usage, it seems to have a different purpose? I really just want to roughly monitor the RAM usage of Discord.

Comment: It monitors a process (once you have set up the filters and you can add events).  And it keeps the data.  Here is an article using perfmon to find [memory leaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-performance-monitor-to-find-a-user-mode-memory-leak).  But I have to say that in 48 years of programming, I have never needed to do what you are looking for.  You can generally find memory leaks with a debugger.